# Redirect the authenticated user to website

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I am redirecting the authenticated user to link of my website from iOS App (user is authenticated from iOS app). There is log in page on website and some other pages. I want to redirect to my website without asking for log in. How can i achieve this?
What is needed to do at iOS side?
What is needed to do at website side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you login through the iOS app, you are receiving back an `authToken` from the server that you can save for further queries. I would recommend sending that token to the server when you redirect and verify the token on server side.

As an added layer of security, you can encrypt your token before sending it to the server and then decrypt it on the other side